# Displaying and Hiding an Element using Cordova

Tags: javascript, html, ios, cordova, mustache

I am very new to coding and am trying to create an app for a study. I am having trouble displaying an element on the correct page of my app using cordova and Xcode. Basically, I want to display a clickable phone number at the end of my app and I am having trouble getting the element to show only on that page (and not on every page of the app). I have figured out how to hide the element, but now I can't get it to appear in the right place. Here is my html code:

```
<script>
            function show(shown, hidden) {
                document.getElementById(shown).style.display='block';
                document.getElementById(hidden).style.display='none';
                return false;
            }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
      <!-- HTML Template -->
      <body onload="app.initialize()">
          <div class="app">
          <div id="window">
              <div id="question">
              </div>
              <div id="popup" style="display:none">
               Please call any of the below:
               Phone System: <a href="tel:+1-800-555-5555" class="button button-positive">800-555-5555</a>
              </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I tried to include the following in my .js file but it did not work:

```
var $prehashval = "";
            function loop()
            {
                if (location.hash.slice(1)!=$prehashval)
                    hashChanged();

                $prehashval = location.hash.slice(1);
                setTimeout("loop()", 100);
            }
            function hashChanged()
            {
                var $output;
                switch (location.hash.slice(1))
                {
                    case "question":
                        document.getElementById('question').style.display = "";
                        document.getElementById('popup').style.display = "none";
                        break;
                    case "popup":
                        document.getElementById('question').style.display = "none";
                        document.getElementById('popup').style.display = "";
                        break;
                    default:
                        $output = location.hash.slice(1);
                }
            }
            loop();
```

I also tried adding the following:

```
$("#popup").hide()  
$("#popup").display()
```

With no luck. Would appreciate any advice! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

With the help of some friends, I have fixed this problem! I added the following code to the .js file:

if (question.variableName === 'popup') {
        $('#popup').show();

Hope this helps someone in the future!